# golang - Raising and handling MySQL disconnection events

Tags: mysql, database, go, event-handling, database-connection

Coming from NodeJs background, I use this snippet to handle MySQL database connection errors. This `npm` [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#error-handling) has more details. I did come across [`go-sql-driver/mysql`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql); but, it didn't describe raising and handling events arising out database connections, etc.

How do we build event-driven applications for MySQL client in Go?

```js
connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});
 
connection.query('USE name_of_db_that_does_not_exist');
```

Comment: use `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")` ; then handle `err`.

Comment: If the above the snippet is used, then for every SQL, the state of the db connection will have to be checked before proceeding. I want to be able to gracefully shut down my application as soon as there is db connection error - regardless of if my application is doing a db or a non-db activity.

Broadly, an application will spend time in db and non-db related activities. In NodeJs, regardless of what the current execution is, the `error` event can be handled to gracefully shut down the application. How do we do that in Go lang?

Comment: Oh~ You want to check out if the connection still alive. I think you can do it better by other middlewares that can do health/status checking. Or you can do as `DB.Ping()` https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Ping to check it out.

Comment: I recommend https://github.com/megaease/easeprobe. It is a simple, standalone, and lightweight tool, writing by Golang.

Comment: `easeprobe` looks good; however, it seems to be a _very powerful_ solution as it connects a source system e.g. MySQL with a notification system e.g. Slack, etc. My requirement is to have an "embedded" solution. Consider [`postal` in NodeJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postal).

Comment: Does `DB.ping()` raise an event that can be handled within the application? Maybe, I am thinking too much NodeJs!

Comment: Of course. You can handle the event in your application after `DB.Ping()`.

Comment: @spike014 the documentation did not mention a ping frequency or a background task to check if the connection is alive. So, should `DB.ping()` be run in a loop? This appears contrary to what an `on('error')` kind of approach in NodeJs.

Comment: See this code comment from golang official https://go.dev/play/p/dmkJlLKN-ZI. You can run `Ping` or `PingContext` in loop for health checking.